# Django: I want to save the dropdown selected display value into databse instead of the name of selected option

Tags: python, django, forms, dropdown

In the forms.py, I have created a application_status widget and added it to the customerForm. it is as below:

```
APPLICATION_STATUS = [
    ('new', 'New'),
    ('processing', 'Processing'),
    ('reject', 'Rejected'),
    ('complete', 'Completed'),
]

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    application_status = forms.CharField(label='What is your application status?',
                                         widget=forms.Select(choices=APPLICATION_STATUS))

    # email_one = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('application_status')
```

And then in the view.py I save selected value in the database, but it saved the name of selected option not display value. For example,I select the option 'Processing' and I want the value 'Processing' to be saved in database. But I see 'processing' is saved. The code is as below:

```
def customer_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer = form.save(commit=False)
            customer.status = request.POST.get('application_status')
            customer.save()
            return redirect('customer_detail', pk=customer.pk)
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
    return render(request, 'customer_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Please help a little bit.

Comment: the first item in the tuple will the one that will be saved in db. you may have the same `APPLICATION_STATUS` in your model, so to display the value expected, you will just need to do `instance.get_field_name_display()` or in templates `{{ instance.get_field_name_display }}`

Comment: customer.status = request.POST.get('application_status') its wrong. It should be customer.status = form.cleaned_data().get('application_status')

Comment: Hi @RyuCoder, I added  customer.status = form.cleaned_data().get('application_status') but i have error: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Remove () after the cleaned_data. It should be like form.cleaned_data.get()

Comment: I used the approach of using {{ instance.get_field_name_display }} in the template, then it displays the value what I wanted. And what I learnt from this is that, we should always store the key into the databse not the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion what it's doing now is correct. It should use the first instance of `APPLICATION_STATUS` to be stored in the database and the second as the display version. If you need the the second value in the tuple to be stored, then change `APPLICATION_STATUS` to reflect that:

```
APPLICATION_STATUS = [
    ('New', 'New'),
    ('Processing', 'Processing'),
    ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),
    ('Completed', 'Completed'),
]
```

But again, in my opinion that would be the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Its does solve the problem of op. It seems wrong but it has one advantage though, when we are reading the value, we dont have call the get_field_name_display() at all. For list view, it would eliminate one for loop from code.

Comment: That's true, but I personally don't like it as a design decision. To each their own.

Comment: Yeah, to each their own 

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is:

```
opciones = (
    ('a','A'),
    ('a1','A1')
    )
class Producto(ModelForm):
      a = forms.ChoiceField(choices=opciones)
```

... With this, the framework will show you a select whit those options...

Comment: I got error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices' in the consolo

Comment: Hi Alerrto, it still save 'a' in the database

Comment: First answer solves your problem. The values that are already in database, you might have to change them manually.